# Error al tratar de descomprimir un archivo .tar.gz con tar -xvzf

Tags: tar, gzip

Estoy ejecutando la siguiente instrucción para descomprimir un archivo .tar.gz

`$tar -xzvf file_name.tar.gz`

pero obtuve el siguiente error.

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error es not recoverable: exiting now
```

¿Qué debería hacer? Gracias

Comment: Las preguntas aquí van en español, incluyendo el título. Puedes [edit]

Comment: Yo probaria dos cosas antes de dar el archivo por perdido:  1)  Usar tar sin la `z` por si acaso no usa la compresión gz.  y 2) Provar de hacer directamente un `gunzip` de ese archivo.  Si funciona en cualquiera de esos casos entonces es que en su momento alguien se confundió de extensión al crearlo o renombrarlo.

Comment: La opción 1 sí funcionó gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegro :-)

Comment: Pongan la respuesta como respuesta! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo probaria dos cosas antes de dar el archivo por perdido: 1) Usar tar sin la z por si acaso no usa la compresión gz. y 2) Provar de hacer directamente un gunzip de ese archivo. Si funciona en cualquiera de esos casos entonces es que en su momento alguien se confundió de extensión al crearlo o renombrarlo. –
masterguru

La ocpión 1 dada por masterguru si funcionó en este caso.